# Warning: Color name "BACKGROUND" is not defined

Tags: vim, centos

I installed CentOS 7 recently and installed vimx. However, everytime I exit vimx, it gives the following warning message:

```
Warning: Color name "BACKGROUND" is not defined
```

I have installed the same thing on CentOS 6 and it was working fine. Is there a way to fix this?

I have removed my ".vimrc" file and it has the same problem.

Comment: What gives that warning message exactly? Is that the whole message? Does it happen with vim as well as vimx (which is gvim?)?

Comment: That's the whole message after exiting vimx. It doesn't happen for vim or gvim.

Comment: I thought vimx was just an alternative name for gvim (at least that's what a few minutes searching online seemed to indicate). Is that not the case? What do `type vimx` and `ls -l "$(type vimx)"` say?

Comment: vimx is a symlink to gvim in my system:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 29 12:40 /usr/bin/vimx -> gvim
However, running it with vimx command launches a vim like editor and running it with gvim command launches a graphical interface. I guess gvim figures it out if it's launched using the vimx command or gvim command and launches different editor.

Comment: Interesting. How does `vimx` differ from `vim` then? Compare the output from `:scriptnames` in vim, gvim, and vimx and maybe you'll find a clue as to where to look.

Comment: `:scriptnames` has the same output for vim and vimx. For gvim, it has two extra files: `/usr/share/vim/vim74/menu.vim` and `/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/paste.vim`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Compare the output of `:colorscheme` and the output of `:set` in them? Something has to be different somewhere or they would all be doing it.